# How do I get the substr value back as original value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I get the correct substr() method value but I couldn't get the original value. Please let me know how to get the original value.

ex) "AAAAAA" -> AA...  but I can't not back AA... -> AAAAAA.

Here is my sample code.

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
    var name= $('#aaa').text();
    var ellipses = name.substr(0, 9) + '...';
    document.getElementById('aaa').innerHTML = ellipses;
} else {
    //scrollTop() < 99 //I would like back the original value. 
}
```

Comment: What return value ? Also this is quite hard to read, maybe you would like to give us more information on what you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would you expect the original value to be there after you wipe it? Once you overwrite the text content of an element, it's gone for good.

You need to save the original value somewhere first, here's an idea:

```
$('#aaa').data('origValue', $('#aaa').text());
if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
    var name = $('#aaa').text();
    var ellipses = name.substr(0, 9) + '...';
    document.getElementById('aaa').innerHTML = ellipses;
} else {
    //scrollTop() < 99 //I would like back the default value. 
    $('#aaa').text($('#aaa').data('origValue'));
}
```

This example uses HTML5 data-* attributes to store the original text and then read it after when you scroll back up. As I said, just an idea, there are tons of other ways to store that text someplace, but **you have to store it**.

---

Here's an example of what you probably want to achieve:

```js
$('#aaa').data('origValue', $('#aaa').text());

$(window).scroll(function(){
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
    var name = $('#aaa').text();
    var ellipses = name.substr(0, 9) + '...';
    document.getElementById('aaa').innerHTML = ellipses;
  } else {
    //scrollTop() < 99 //I would like back the default value. 
    $('#aaa').text($('#aaa').data('origValue'));
  }
});
```

```css
div {padding: 120px 0; min-height: 300px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="aaa">Some super-mega-long text here! Try scrolling...</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

While the other answer is perfectly correct, you can store the value somewhere.

Another approach would be to simple truncate the item in the `view` using `css`.

A `css` class like :

```
.truncate {
  width: 35px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

This could be applied when the scroll is required :

```
$('#aaa').addClass("truncate");
```

Then when the scroll is > 100 :

```
$('#aaa').removeClass("truncate");
```

This way the value is not manipulated, just the users view. Also transitions could be added later to make thing more pretty.

Again this is just 1 other solution!

Comment: Lovely, a +1 from me!

Comment: Thank you but I just need JS